# Last column of the table doesn't comply with linewidth argument

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table with some sentences (long text) inside cells. I need a table that fits to my page, therefore I specify column widths so the text automatically goes to the next line. The last column doesn't comply `m{0.2\linewidth}` argument which drives me crazy. Am I missing a small detail here? How can I make sure my last column fits to its width specification?

PS: I am fairly new at using LaTeX.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{m{0.1\linewidth}m{0.25\linewidth}c{0.15\linewidth} c{0.15\linewidth}m{0.2\linewidth}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Test}&
    \multirow{2}{*}{$H_0$}&
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Test Statistic}&
    \multirow{2}{*}{Result}
    \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    &
    &
    Model 1 &
    Model 2 &
    \\ \midrule
    F-Test  &
    There are no individual time-invariant effects, it is preferable to estimate by pooled OLS.&                  
    $p<0.001^{***}$ & $p<0.001^{***}$ &        
    Null hypothesis rejected, time-fixed effects exist and thus fixed effects modelling is preferred over a pooled OLS model.    
    \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{The results of robustness tests} 
\label{tests}
\end{table}
```

This looks like this in my screen:
[image]

I would like to make sure my last column looks like the 2nd one (H0).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages and definitions (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) How is your `c` column type defined? The default `c` column type does not accept a width argument, so I would expect your code to result in an error message.

Comment: Since I assume, the screenshot you show shows the "output"  of a compilation that resulted in the befor mentioned error messages: Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: I currently don't really see the need for fixed width columns for columns 1, 3 and 4, so a simple `\begin{tabular}{lm{0.25\linewidth}c cm{0.2\linewidth}}` shoud work perfectly fine. If you want to use the available space more efficiently, you may want to consider using `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXc cX}` instead (needs the `tabularx` package)

Comment: Dear leandriis, both suggestions worked fine! Thank you very much. Also, thank you for your suggestion on code compilability and adding documentclass, I will try to include them next time!

Comment: Just one last question: Is there a way I can still vertically mid-center the cells in my 1st, 3rd and 4th columns? Actually even better for all columns. Using `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXccX}` doesn't do that.

Comment: you can instruct tabularx to use `m` rather than `p` columns for `X` see the package documentation.

Comment: Dear David Carlisle, I found the package documentation and indeed it is possible to change it like this for anyone who is interested: `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}` Thanks!

Comment: Using the code in your comment will not only result in vertically centered contents in X type columns, but will also reduce the font size to small. If you want to avoid that, remove >{\small}